# Statelist drawable for different resource types

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got resources for different screens in drawable-ldpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi. Where should I place [Statelist](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) file? I mean, that xml could be one for all types of resources, so in what folder shoudl I place it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a folder inside `/res`: `drawable`, and put your state list xml in that folder.
It can be referenced as `R.drawable.your_state_list`.

This way you will have only one xml which will be used for all the resolutions.
If you have other common drawables, you can place them here too.

Answer (score 0):

can create a folder named `drawable`in `res`folder and you can place your `statelist.xml` in that so that it can be used.